# Java BigDecimal: Round to the nearest whole value

Tags: java, rounding, bigdecimal

I need the following results

```
100.12 -> 100.00
100.44 -> 100.00
100.50 -> 101.00
100.75 -> 101.00
```

`.round()` or `.setScale()` ? How do I go about this?

Answer (score 191, accepted):

You can use `setScale()` to reduce the number of fractional digits to zero. Assuming `value` holds the value to be rounded:

```
BigDecimal scaled = value.setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
System.out.println(value + " -> " + scaled);
```

Using `round()` is a bit more involved as it requires you to specify the number of digits to be retained. In your examples this would be 3, but this is not valid for all values:

```
BigDecimal rounded = value.round(new MathContext(3, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
System.out.println(value + " -> " + rounded);
```

(Note that `BigDecimal` objects are immutable; both `setScale` and `round` will return a new object.)

Comment: It's not working: 100.12 : 100.12, 100.44 : 100.44, 100.50 : 100.5, 
100.75 : 100.75

Comment: No, setting scale returns a new decimal that isn't same as the first. For example:`BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal(100.12); BigDecimal bd2 = bd1.setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP); System.out.println(bd1.equals(bd2));` prints false

Comment: @Daniel: That was already implied in the code snippet I posted in my answer. I've now made it explicit.

Comment: `RoundingMode` what is that?  It's `BigDecimal`

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale-int-java.math.RoundingMode-

Answer (score 17):

If i go by Grodriguez's answer

```
System.out.println("" + value);
value = value.setScale(0, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
System.out.println("" + value);
```

This is the output

```
100.23 -> 100
100.77 -> 101
```

Which isn't quite what i want, so i ended up doing this..

```
System.out.println("" + value);
value = value.setScale(0, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
value = value.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
System.out.println("" + value);
```

This is what i get

```
100.23 -> 100.00
100.77 -> 101.00
```

This solves my problem for now .. : )
Thank you all.

Comment: I am curious about the statement that the first result "isn't quite what I want...". If you are actually concerned about output formatting, you can use `DecimalFormat` (as in `new DecimalFormat("###.00")` ) to manage the conversion of a `BigDecimal` back to string. It gives `"101.00"` as the result for both values that the snippets from @Grodriquez and you created.

Comment: The second time you are rounding here is unnecessary as you know you have an integer already, so I would use BigDecimal.ROUND_UNNECESSARY instead, a bit more clear in my opinion.

Comment: Answer needs updating (due to deprecation).
Should be **value.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)**

Answer (score 5):

Here's an awfully complicated solution, but it works:

```
public static BigDecimal roundBigDecimal(final BigDecimal input){
    return input.round(
        new MathContext(
            input.toBigInteger().toString().length(),
            RoundingMode.HALF_UP
        )
    );
}
```

**Test Code:**

```
List<BigDecimal> bigDecimals =
    Arrays.asList(new BigDecimal("100.12"),
        new BigDecimal("100.44"),
        new BigDecimal("100.50"),
        new BigDecimal("100.75"));
for(final BigDecimal bd : bigDecimals){
    System.out.println(roundBigDecimal(bd).toPlainString());
}
```

**Output:**

> 100
>   100
>   101
>   101

Comment: Not to endorse this solution or anything, but the `input.toBigInteger().toString().length()` part would be much more efficient by using a logarithm, some thing like `round_up(log(input)) + (1 if input is a power of ten, else 0)`

Comment: BigDecimal seems like a steaming heap.

Answer (score 3):

Simply look at:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ROUND_HALF_UP

and:

```
setScale(int precision, int roundingMode)
```

Or if using Java 6, then

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_UP

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/MathContext.html

and either:

```
setScale(int precision, RoundingMode mode);
round(MathContext mc);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can round it like that in a single command. Try

```
    ArrayList<BigDecimal> list = new ArrayList<BigDecimal>();
    list.add(new BigDecimal("100.12"));
    list.add(new BigDecimal("100.44"));
    list.add(new BigDecimal("100.50"));
    list.add(new BigDecimal("100.75"));

    for (BigDecimal bd : list){
        System.out.println(bd+" -> "+bd.setScale(0,RoundingMode.HALF_UP).setScale(2));
    }

Output:
100.12 -> 100.00
100.44 -> 100.00
100.50 -> 101.00
100.75 -> 101.00
```

I tested for the rest of your examples and it returns the wanted values, but I don't guarantee its correctness.

Answer (score 0):

If neither `.round()` nor `.setScale()` seem intuitive to you, you can use this code to round to any integer steps of precision (e.g. round in 10s, 25s, 50s, 100s, ...).

Usage:

```
int distance = roundN(_distance, 5);
```

Declaration:

```
public static BigDecimal roundN(BigDecimal num, int precision){
    BigDecimal remainder = num.remainder(BigDecimal.valueOf(precision));
    System.out.println("remainder: " + remainder);

    if (remainder.compareTo(BigDecimal.valueOf((precision / 2))) < 0 ){
        System.out.println("round down");
        return num.subtract(remainder);
    } else {
        BigDecimal neg = remainder.negate().add(BigDecimal.valueOf(precision));
        System.out.println("round up");
        return num.add(neg);
    }
}
```

Trailing `.00`  can be appended to the result on demand.

Answer (score -2):

You want

```
round(new MathContext(0));  // or perhaps another math context with rounding mode HALF_UP
```

Comment: This does nothing. From the documentation of `round`: "If the precision setting is 0 then no rounding takes place."