# BigDecimal round to 0 or 5

Tags: android, rounding, bigdecimal

I'm tinkering with `BigDecimal` and currency formatting in Android, and was wondering if it was possible to do the following using `BigDecimal`:

**What I desire:**

```
  64.99 --> 65.00 (Rounded Up)
  64.99 --> 60.00 (Rounded Down)
  65.01 --> 70.00 (Rounded Up)
  65.01 --> 65.00 (Rounded Down)
```

At present, with my code below, I'm only able to round to zeros. For example:

**What I get:**

```
  64.99 --> 70.00 (Rounded Up)
  64.99 --> 60.00 (Rounded Down)
  65.01 --> 70.00 (Rounded Up)
  65.01 --> 60.00 (Rounded Down)
```

Is there a way using `BigDecimal` to achieve what I desire?

My code:

```
private static void printRoundedValues() {
    NumberFormat currencyFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    BigDecimal valueUp = new BigDecimal(64.50, new MathContext(1,RoundingMode.UP));
    BigDecimal valueDown = new BigDecimal(64.50, new MathContext(1,RoundingMode.DOWN)); 

    System.out.println("Value Up: " +  currencyFormat.format(valueUp));
    System.out.println("Value Down: " +  currencyFormat.format(valueDown));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can multiply by `2`, then round to the nearest `10`, then divide by `2`.  The precision is `2` for these `BigDecimals`; it may need to be different for `BigDecimals` of different scale.

```
BigDecimal[] bds = {new BigDecimal("64.99"), new BigDecimal("65.01")};
BigDecimal two = new BigDecimal("2");
MathContext mcUp = new MathContext(2, RoundingMode.UP);
MathContext mcDown = new MathContext(2, RoundingMode.DOWN);
NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
for (BigDecimal bd : bds)
{
    System.out.println("Test: " + bd);
    BigDecimal roundUp5 = bd.multiply(two).round(mcUp).divide(two);
    System.out.println("Round up: " + currency.format(roundUp5));
    BigDecimal roundDown5 = bd.multiply(two).round(mcDown).divide(two);
    System.out.println("Round down: " + currency.format(roundDown5));
}
```

Output:

```
Test: 64.99
Round up: $65.00
Round down: $60.00
Test: 65.01
Round up: $70.00
Round down: $65.00
```

Comment: And never use a `new BigDecimal(65.99)` but `new BigDecimal("65.99")`. Doubles are an approximation, a sum of (negative) powers of 2. And with a String the precision is known for BigDecimal.

Comment: This is a nice solution plus it gives sensible values. Thank you. @JoopEggen thank you for the tip, that actually saves me some cycles as I was parsing to float then creating a BigDecimal, now I can just pass in the string.

Answer (score 0):

```java
    NumberFormat currencyFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    BigDecimal valueUp = new BigDecimal(64.50, new MathContext(2, RoundingMode.UP));
    BigDecimal valueDown = new BigDecimal(64.50, new MathContext(2, RoundingMode.DOWN));

    System.out.println("Value Up: " +  currencyFormat.format(valueUp));
    System.out.println("Value Down: " +  currencyFormat.format(valueDown));
```

**Here is how MathContext precision works:**

- creates a value (64.5)
- set the precision to given value (2) which results in 64.5
- round this value using given RoundingMode (UP), which gives you the value of 65

**You probably need to set scale rather than precision:**

```
    BigDecimal valueUp = new BigDecimal(64.50).setScale(0, RoundingMode.UP);
    BigDecimal valueDown = new BigDecimal(64.50).setScale(0, RoundingMode.DOWN);
```

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is setScale and is part of BigDecimal.

Here is a good answer to the same question:
[Java BigDecimal: Round to the nearest whole value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134047/java-bigdecimal-round-to-the-nearest-whole-value)