# How to get in Java all output paths of a JSONpath in order to replace existing values by a function of themseleves

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

Let's say I have this .json on witch I want to apply a function that round up the price of the book:

```
{
"store": {
    "book": [
        {
            "category": "reference",
            "author": "Nigel Rees",
            "title": "Sayings of the Century",
            "price": 8.95
        },
        {
            "category": "fiction",
            "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
            "title": "Sword of Honour",
            "price": 12.99
        },
        {
            "category": "fiction",
            "author": "Herman Melville",
            "title": "Moby Dick",
            "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
            "price": 8.99
        },
        {
            "category": "fiction",
            "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
            "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
            "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
            "price": 22.99
        }
    ],
    "bicycle": {
        "color": "red",
        "price": 19.95
    }
},
"expensive": 10
}
```

The idea I had for doing that was to specify the jsonpath

```
$.store.book[*].price
```

and get in return the list of ouput path (like on this website: https://jsonpath.com/ )

```
[ "$.store.book[0].price", "$.store.book[1].price", "$.store.book[2].price", "$.store.book[3].price" ]
```

or even better a direct mapping between the path and the value

```
[ {"$.store.book[0].price":8.95}, {"$.store.book[1].price":12.99}, {"$.store.book[2].price":8.99}, {"$.store.book[3].price":22.99} ]
```

and then making a loop over the list to apply the function on each value and setting the json with the new value

But i can't find how to get that list of path, how can i do that ? (or if you have something to directly replace the value by a function of themselves, i would take it too :) )

PS: the .json I give is just an example, I need it for .json way more nested than that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list path you need to parse document with configuration object. After that you need to parse it once more time for updating:

```
import com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.Option;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.JsonContext;

import java.io.File;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class JsonPathApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        // read paths
        List<String> paths = JsonPath
                .using(Configuration.builder().options(Option.AS_PATH_LIST).build())
                .parse(jsonFile)
                .read("$.store.book[*].price", List.class);

        // compile paths
        List<JsonPath> jsonPaths = paths
                .stream()
                .map(p -> JsonPath.compile(p))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        // parse once for reading/updating
        JsonContext document = (JsonContext) JsonPath.parse(jsonFile);
        jsonPaths.forEach(path -> {
            BigDecimal value = document.read(path, BigDecimal.class);
            document.set(path, transform(value));
        });

        System.out.println(document.jsonString());
    }

    private static BigDecimal transform(BigDecimal value) {
        return value.setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
{
  "store": {
    "book": [
      {
        "category": "reference",
        "author": "Nigel Rees",
        "title": "Sayings of the Century",
        "price": 9
      },
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
        "title": "Sword of Honour",
        "price": 13
      },
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Herman Melville",
        "title": "Moby Dick",
        "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
        "price": 9
      },
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
        "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
        "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
        "price": 23
      }
    ],
    "bicycle": {
      "color": "red",
      "price": 19.95
    }
  },
  "expensive": 10
}
```

See also:

- [JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath)
- [Java BigDecimal: Round to the nearest whole value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134047/java-bigdecimal-round-to-the-nearest-whole-value)

Comment: Thanks you very much, that's exactly what I was looking for !

Comment: @Uryendel, I'm glad to hear that. You are new user, please take a loot at [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)