# How to query JSON with wildcards and modify the results?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonpath, javax.json

I'd like to be able to query a JSON object and modify it in a way that is structure-agnostic and doesn't involve marshalling to POJOs. Here's an example to illustrate.

```
{
  "user" : [ {
    "username" : "foo",
    "user-id" : "1234",
    "name" : {
      "first-name" : "John",
      "last-name" : "Smith"
    },
    "ssn": "123-45-6789"
  }, {
    "username" : "bar",
    "user-id" : "1235",
    "name" : {
      "first-name" : "Jane",
      "last-name" : "Doe"
    },
    "ssn": "098-76-5432"
  } ]
}
```

What I want to do is this:
Get the `ssn` nodes, retrieve their values, encrypt them, put the encrypted values back in the JSON, and return the whole thing. I've found two ways to do this so far:

1. Marshalling to a User `POJO`
2. Writing a method that iterates over the "user"s directly and modifies the `ssn` value.

The problem with either approach is that I have to generate "user" specific code. This is fine when I have only one data format, but I'm going to have dozens. I want to work more agnostically. Ideally I can do this with a line like this:

```
List<JsonNode> ssnNodes = jsonObj.match("$.user[*].ssn");
```

and then just iterate over the list -- just as I can with XML using `XPath`. This way I can maintain a list of json-paths to query with and that is as much as I need to know about the data.

Someone please tell me there is a way to do this in Java, but I haven't found a way so far. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your input is raw `JSON` payload you should use `JsonPath` to scan and change fields. If your input is a `Java` model you can write custom serialisers for specific fields. For example: [Jackson custom serialization and deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55249054/jackson-custom-serialization-and-deserialization).

Comment: JsonPath is a great tool but unless I am missing something it seems I can't use it the way I am hoping to. Reading a JsonPath string with wildcards seems to return a list of values, not references to nodes in a document model, as I can do with javax.xml.xpath. So there's no way to iterate over a list of nodes, I have to iterate over a list of "users," which is the kind of code I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: I've also looked at Jackson's JsonPointer implementation, but it doesn't offer any sort of wildcard querying at all.

Comment: You can do that using `Option.AS_PATH_LIST` option. Take a look on this question and my answer: [How to get in Java all output paths of a JSONpath in order to replace existing values by a function of themseleves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55423089/how-to-get-in-java-all-output-paths-of-a-jsonpath-in-order-to-replace-existing-v). Also, you can play with online tool [jsonpath.herokuapp](http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/) but select `Normalized path expressions` option instead of `Matching values`.

Comment: I will take a deeper look at that - thank you Michal!