# How to Round a BigDecimal in java

Tags: java, android, rounding, bigdecimal

I have an extremely large number and I use the BigDecimal type,

But now I want to round up a BigDecimal, as follows:
If the number is **10803432.12**, it will round down to **10803432** and if the number is **10803432.69**, it will round to **10803433**
So how to do it,
My Code:

```
        BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal("10803432.12");
        MathContext mc = new MathContext(0);
        System.out.println(bigDecimal.round(mc));
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134047/java-bigdecimal-round-to-the-nearest-whole-value think this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {
    BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal("10803432.12");
    bigDecimal = bigDecimal.setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);      
    System.out.println(bigDecimal);

    bigDecimal = new BigDecimal("10803432.69");
    bigDecimal = bigDecimal.setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    System.out.println(bigDecimal);
}
```

**output**

```
10803432
10803433
```