# Rounding of BigDecimal

Tags: java, rounding, bigdecimal

I want to do rounding of Bigdecimal e.g my 0.1 then it should round as 1.
I tried with Round_UP, all Rounding Function
Please help me out

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134047/java-bigdecimal-round-to-the-nearest-whole-value , does this answer your question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you used the `round` method. Instead, you should change the scale to `0`.

```
BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.1);
BigDecimal rounded = bd.setScale(0, RoundingMode.UP); // 1
```